# Get MIN MAX grouping by closer distance

Tags: sql, postgresql

**shops**

```
id_shop | id_prod_ty | position
```

and

**products**

```
id | price | id_prod_ty | distance
```

table shops contains 2 shops for each id_prod_ty (product type) and a position.
table products contains many records with different prices and a distance

basically i need to have a query that selects price low and high for each product and for each shops grouping by closer prices (and that are not closer to other shops)

so for example

**shops**

```
id_shop | id_prod_ty | position
  1     |     1      |    3
  2     |     1      |    7
  3     |     2      |    8
  4     |     2      |    4
....
```

**products**

```
id | price | id_prod_ty | distance
1  |  10   |   1        |  1        
2  |  04   |   1        |  2 
3  |  02   |   1        |  4 
4  |  44   |   1        |  2 
5  |  09   |   1        |  1 
6  |  13   |   1        |  7
7  |  15   |   1        |  8
8  |  09   |   2        |  5 
9  |  12   |   2        |  8
10 |  17   |   2        |  1
11 |  32   |   2        | 13
12 |  22   |   2        |  2
...
```

result shout be like this

```
id_prod_ty | id_price_low | id_price_high | id_shop
1          |     3 (02)   |      4 (44)   |  1
1          |     6 (13)   |      7 (15)   |  2
2          |     8 (09)   |     12 (22)   |  4
2          |     9 (12)   |     11 (32)   |  3
...
```

thanks

Comment: It's not clear to me how the end result is calculated.  Could you explain what you mean by "grouping by closer prices (and that are not closer to other shops)" ?

Comment: +1 includes sample data. Please add your PostgreSQL version, though.

Comment: lets take id_shop 1 and 2. Closer prices that belongs to shop 1 are: 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, because the distance is close to shop1 than to shop2, shop3 and so on. Prices 6 and 7 belongs to shop2 for the same reason. hope this clarify
pg 9.2

Comment: @user1944934 . . . What is the connection between `shops` and `products`?  Is this the problem you are trying to solve?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I understand the problem.  For each price, you are trying to assign the shop that is nearest, based on the distance and the position.

The approach starts by joining the positions and shops.  It then calculates the difference between the position and distance -- that seems to be the measure you are using.  Each price id will appear twice (once for each shop).  Using a window function, it calculates the minimum difference for each id.

With this information, the query can determine which is the closer shop.  This version returns the prices, rather than the ids of the lowest prices. Here is the final, untested, query:

```
select id_prod_ty,
       MIN(case when diff = minDiff then price) as price_low,
       MAX(case when diff = minDiff then price) as price_high,
       s.id_shop
from (select p.id_prod_ty,
             s.id_shop,
             p.price,
             (p.distance - s.position) as diff,
             MIN(p.distance - s.position) over (partition by p.id) as minDiff
      from products p join
           shops s
           on p.id_prod_ty = s.id_prod_ty
    ) ps
group by id_prod_ty, id_shop
```

Here is a variation that gets the ids as well.  It uses a window function to find the min and max price, and then compares the price to these values to get the ids:

```
select id_prod_ty,
       MIN(minPrice) as price_low,
       MIN(case when price = minPrice then id end) id_price_low,
       MAX(maxprice) as price_high,
       MIN(case when price = maxPrice then id end) id_price_high,
       id_shop
from (select *,
             MIN(IsThisShopPrice) over (partition by id_prod_ty, id_shop) as minPrice,
             MIN(IsThisShopPrice) over (partition by id_prod_ty, id_shop) as maxPrice,
      from (select p.id_prod_ty, s.id_shop, p.price, p.id,
                   (p.distance - s.position) as diff,
                   (case when (p.distance - s.position) = MIN(p.distance - s.position) over (partition by p.id)
                         then 'Y'
                         else 'N'
                    end) as IsThisShop
                   (case when (p.distance - s.position) = MIN(p.distance - s.position) over (partition by p.id)
                         then price
                    end) as IsThisShopPrice
            from products p join
                 shops s
                 on p.id_prod_ty = s.id_prod_ty
           ) ps
    ) ps
group by id_prod_ty, id_shop
```

Comment: we have almost done Gordon, 
I had fixed some errors in query (ps instad of p) 

but what I have unexpected null values,  

id_prod_ty | id_price_low | id_price_high | id_shop
1          |     null     |      null     |  1
1          |     2        |      44       |  2
2          |     9        |     32        |  4
2          |     null     |     null      |  5

silly question, how to obtain id instead of prices? ( I cannot join since many values with same prices)
appreciated

Comment: You will have NULL values when a shop is too far away, so no prices are closest to it.

Comment: I have to study your query in order to get rid of that blank value. thanks